# Goで[]byteをshift-jisの文字列に変換する

Tags: go, shift-jis

Golangで[]byteをshift-jisの文字列に変換するにはどうすればいいのでしょうか?
Pythonだとbytes.decode("shift-jis")とかで一発でできるのですが・・・
デフォルトがutf-8なので `string([]byte)` としてもshift-jisにならずutf-8になってしまうと思うのですがどうすればいいのでしょうか?

Comment: 質問の意図は shift-jis の格納されている `[]byte` を utf-8 の `string` に変換したいということでしょうか。golangのstringはPython3 の bytes (Python2 のstr) に近い単なるバイト列なので 質問文を文字通り受け取ると `string([]byte)` でshift-jisで文字列が格納されてる `string` が作れるというのが答えになってしまいますが、おそらくそういう意味ではないですよね....
http://blog.golang.org/strings

Comment: `デフォルトがutf-8なので string([]byte) としてもshift-jisにならずutf-8になってしまう` たしかに、ここの認識が違うだけだったかもしれませんね。。。 ShiftJIS の []byte を作りたいということか。既に回答してしまいましたが、ちと修正します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

エンコードの変換には、定番の [`text.encoding`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding) パッケージを使用しますが、`code.google.com/p/go.text/encoding` パッケージは**使わないでください**。 去年末 (Go 1.4 に先駆けて) から推奨されるパッケージ名が変わりました。現在では `golang.org/x/text/encoding` パッケージが使われます。

*サンプルコード* :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "golang.org/x/text/transform"
//  "code.google.com/p/go.text/transform" // deprecated
    "golang.org/x/text/encoding/japanese"
//  "code.google.com/p/go.text/encoding/japanese" // deprecated
)

func transformEncoding( rawReader io.Reader, trans transform.Transformer) (string, error) {
    ret, err := ioutil.ReadAll(transform.NewReader(rawReader, trans))
    if err == nil {
        return string(ret), nil
    } else {
        return "", err
    }
}

// Convert a string encoding from ShiftJIS to UTF-8
func FromShiftJIS(str string) (string, error) {
    return transformEncoding(strings.NewReader(str), japanese.ShiftJIS.NewDecoder())
}

// Convert a string encoding from UTF-8 to ShiftJIS
func ToShiftJIS(str string) (string, error) {
    return transformEncoding(strings.NewReader(str), japanese.ShiftJIS.NewEncoder())
}

// Convert an array of bytes (a valid ShiftJIS string) to a UTF-8 string
func BytesFromShiftJIS(b []byte) (string, error) {
    return transformEncoding(bytes.NewReader(b), japanese.ShiftJIS.NewDecoder())
}

// Convert an array of bytes (a valid UTF-8 string) to a ShiftJIS string
func BytesToShiftJIS(b []byte) (string, error) {
    return transformEncoding(bytes.NewReader(b), japanese.ShiftJIS.NewEncoder())
}

func main() {
    strRaw := "\x8c\x8e\x93\xfa\x82\xcd\x95\x53\x91\xe3\x82\xcc\x89\xdf\x8b\x71" +
            "\x82\xc9\x82\xb5\x82\xc4\x81\x41\x8d\x73\x82\xa9\x82\xd3\x94\x4e" +
            "\x82\xe0\x96\x94\x97\xb7\x90\x6c\x96\xe7\x81\x42"

    strUTF := "月日は百代の過客にして、行かふ年も又旅人也。"

    // string (ShiftJIS) -> []byte (ShiftJIS)
    bytesRaw := []byte(strRaw)

    // string (UTF-8) -> []byte (UTF-8)
    bytesUTF := []byte(strUTF)

    // string (ShiftJIS) -> string (UTF-8)
    {
        result, err := FromShiftJIS(strRaw)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(result)
    }

    // []byte (ShiftJIS) -> string (UTF-8)
    {
        result, err := BytesFromShiftJIS(bytesRaw)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(result)
    }

    // []byte (UTF-8) -> string (ShiftJIS)
    {
        result, err := BytesToShiftJIS(bytesUTF)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("ByteToShiftJIS: %t", result == strRaw)
    }
}
```

*Output*:

```
月日は百代の過客にして、行かふ年も又旅人也。
月日は百代の過客にして、行かふ年も又旅人也。
ByteToShiftJIS: true
```

参考:

- GoDoc: [`golang.org/x/text/encoding`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding)
- GoDoc: [`golang.org/x/text/transform/Transformer`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/transform#Transformer)
- golang-nuts: [New import paths for Go sub-respositories](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/eD8dh3T9yyA)

Answer (score 2):

`text/transform`の[transform.String](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/transform#String) を使って変換することもできます。

2年前に解決済みの質問ではありますが、`transform.String`の使用例が検索であまり引っかからなかったので、参考までにまとめておきます。

サンプルコード:

```
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/text/encoding/japanese"
    "golang.org/x/text/transform"
    "fmt"
)

func GetSjis(target string) string {
    //utf-8->sjis
    text, count, err := transform.String(japanese.ShiftJIS.NewEncoder(), target)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("バイト数: %v\n", count)
    return text
}

func main()  {
    s := "あ" //utf-8
    fmt.Printf("%v: %x\n", s, s)
    s = GetSjis(s) //sjisに変換
    fmt.Printf("%x\n", s)
    bytes := []byte{0x82, 0xA0}
    //sjis->utf-8変換
    s, _, _ = transform.String(japanese.ShiftJIS.NewDecoder(), string(bytes)) //string(bytes)の代わりにsを用いても結果は同じ
    fmt.Printf("%v: %x\n", s, s)
}
```

Output:

```
あ: e38182
バイト数: 3
82a0
あ: e38182
```